# Logic to create Django web app for adding quiz questions

Tags: django

I have an existing web app using django for creating following type of questions

- MCQs
- Single answer questions

I want to add a new type of question which takes a long text paragraph (like a case study, or a passage for reading comprehension) followed by 5-6 questions that are based on this paragraph. These questions can be MCQs or Single answer questions.

I have exiting code for mcqs and saqs ( single answer questions) which implements three models

- one model for mcqs
- Second model for saqs
- Third model for type of question ( saqs are further of following three types - very short answer, short answer and long answer).

For implementing this mew question type, I would prefer to use same mcq or saq models.

I am not able to figure out what should be a goo and efficient logic.

Answer (score 0):

The most intuitive and efficient way to organize the questions would be within a single Questions model, containing all questions. The type of question shouldn't be managed at the model level, but rather at the field (question) level.

The question type affects a) what kind of data is allowed to be stored in the database and b) how the response is presented to the user. Both will be affected by specifying the field type and attributes. The rendering can be further adjusted in the forms.py file if required.

For example, in your models.py file:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    
    # define choices for multiple choice questions

    question_one_choices = [
        ('0', _('Smaller 1x')),
        ('1', _('1-2x')),
        ('2', _('Larger 2x')),
    ]

    yes_no = [
        (True, _('Yes')),
        (False, _('No')),
    ]

    # multiple choice
    question_one = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=question_one_choices)

    # multiple choice with only 2 options
    question_two = models.BooleanField(choices=yes_no)

    # text answer short
    question_three = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # text answer long
    question_four = models.TextField()
```